# Are there any issues with Selenium v2.53 and Firefox v45.0.1?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, firefoxdriver

I have a couple of tests, which I run them on windows and I have a successful run.
But when I move to UBUNTU server with Xvfb, I faced problem with tests, some of them failed!!

both cases I used:

- Maven 3.1
- Selenide v3.5
- Selenium v2.53
- Firefox v45.0.1

So from where these problems? is it related to Firefox version? or I have to modify in the code somewhere?

some of them can't run:

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

and others can't find elements while executing.

Answer (score 3):

> *If you are using Selenium v-2.53 downgrade your Mozilla Firefox version.
>   Selenium v-2.53 has lots of issues with Mozilla Firefox version above 45. So you may use FF v-31.0. Even I have got same issue with this version & It was resolved with Selenium v-2.52 & FF V-31.0*

Answer (score 1):

That's a connection issue between Selenium and Firefox. There is an open bug on it [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1915) that has some information for potential a work-around.

The issue, from what I have been able to tell is Firefox 45+ is having issues with Multithreading on a single node from Selenium. Potential fix, untested by me and from the bug report linked above, would be to downgrade Firefox.

Comment: is it solved at Selenium v2.53 ?

Comment: From the link, I would say no. It looks like issues with Selenium and FF45 with multi-threading onto a single node.